# can we have memory preservation for chatting in llama-index?

Tags: python, llama-index

I would like to know whether llama-index can be used for creating a custom chatgpt based on the documentation or not. I have an ample amount of data, however, I want to retain context, and add answer the questions accordingly. Is it possible to do that ? if yes then how ? any leads would be really helpful

Answer (score -1):

Yes llama_index can be used to create custom chatbot. There are many online articles and videos explaining this process.

First need to import the below packages.

```
from llama_index import ServiceContext, SimpleDirectoryReader, GPTVectorStoreIndex, LLMPredictor, PromptHelper, StorageContext, load_index_from_storage
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
import os
```

We need to set the open ai key as below:

```
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "your api key"
```

We need to start by creating a vector store based on the data available. Can use the below code to create a vector store. In the below the local data files are stored as pdfs in the folder "Knowledge" and the created index will be stored in the folder "storage".

```
def construct_index():
    def construct_index():
    max_input_size = 4096
    num_outputs = 512
    max_chunk_overlap = 1
    chunk_size_limit = 1000

    print("Index building started")
    prompt_helper = PromptHelper(
        max_input_size, num_outputs, max_chunk_overlap, chunk_size_limit=chunk_size_limit)

    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=ChatOpenAI(
        temperature=0.1, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", max_tokens=num_outputs))

    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=llm_predictor,
        prompt_helper=prompt_helper)

    # load data from the folder
    documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("Knowledge").load_data() 

    index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents, service_context=service_context)

    index.storage_context.persist("storage")

    print("Index created successfully!")
```

Once the index is created, questions related to the local data can be asked by querying this index. indexPath variable refers to the folder where the vector index is stored.

```
def post():
    args = parser.parse_args()
    indexPath = 'storage'

    storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir=indexPath)
    index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context)
    query_engine = index.as_query_engine()
    prompt = args['q']
    response = query_engine.query(prompt)

    return response.response
```

It is important to note that the quality and accuracy of answers depends on the quality of the content fed.

Comment: this question is for answering questions given a data, however, I wanted to know how can I retain memory of this question, and ask the next one

Comment: you can retain memory by using conversational agents in langchain. You can read further in https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/agent_types/chat_conversation_agent/